# WCAG compliant upload with progress bar

Tags: upload, progress-bar, wcag

My searches have revealed a dizzying number of widgets for uploading files while giving some progress feedback to the user.

[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) and [fineuploader](http://fineuploader.com/) are great examples... that I would love to use...

But these, and others seem to be lacking some basic keyboard functionality. My site needs to be WCAG AA compliant. Does anyone know of an uploader (with progress bar) that I could use? Did I miss something in the above mentioned tools?

Comment: Hi!  I'm the maintainer for Fine Uploader.  What sort of specific keyboard support do you require?

Comment: @Ray Nicholus Hi Ray, I was looking at the manual upload jQuery example. Our consultant pointed out 2 problems: the upload button (which is actually a div) doesn't receive keyboard focus and the error messages are not associated with the button when they are triggered.

Those are pretty basic, so the consultant stopped there and suggested we try and find something else. If you're willing we might be able to work together to make at least 1 version of FineUploader 'accessible'.

Comment: I'd certainly like to explore further.  Perhaps you could open up a case in Fine Uploader's github project so this can be discussed and tracked?  https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/issues

Comment: @grayob any updates on this? I'm also working on a GoC website that needs to be WCAG and I'm simply thinking building my own WET plugin.

Comment: @MrJinPengyou No updates yet. I decided not to pursue this until after we rolled out our new WCAG compliant website. Now that we are compliant though, I'm hoping I can get to it soon... possibly within the next couple months.